# java - Unable to add Key in my TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

When I'm calling the setDomainDocumentationMap referencing it from the following code from package MMTUtil.java

```
public class MMTUtil
{

    private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap = null;
    private static Map<String, String> domainComboDocumentationMap = null;

    static
    {
        domainDocumentationMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        domainComboDocumentationMap =new TreeMap<String, String>();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
        return domainDocumentationMap;
    }

    public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap) {
        MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap = domainDocumentationMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getDomainComboDocumentationMap() {
        return domainComboDocumentationMap;
    }

    public static void setDomainComboDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainComboDocumentationMap) {
        MMTUtil.domainComboDocumentationMap = domainComboDocumentationMap;
    }
}
```

And then using it here

```
private UMRMetadataSupportDAOImpl dao;
public UMRResultObject insertDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO)
{
    Session     session = UMRHibernateUtil.getUmrSession();
    Transaction tx      = null;
    documentationLink = null;
    objectName = null;
    objectType = null;


    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        dao.insertDocumentation(documentationDTO, session);
        MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName.getDomainName(),String.valueOf(objectType.getDomainType()));
        MMTUtil.getDomainComboDocumentationMap().put(objectName.getDomainName(),String.valueOf(objectType.getDomainType()));
        MMTUtil.setDomainDocumentationMap(,documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());
        MMTUtil.setDomainComboDocumentationMap(,documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());

        tx.commit();
        ro.setSuccess(true);
        ro.getMessages().add("Record Inserted Successfully");
    }
```

I'm unable to call the domainDocumentationMap from MMTUtil.java to use it in the

```
MMTUtil.setDomainDocumentationMap(,documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());
```

I have created the doa object form this class
    public class UMRMetadataSupportDAOImpl
    extends UMRDAOImplAbstract
{

```
/** logger UMRMetadataSupportDAOImpl */
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UMRMetadataSupportDAOImpl.class);

/**
 * @return List<UMRDTO>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UMRDTO> getDocumentationDomainNamesList(Session session)
{
    List<UMRDTO> objectNamesList  = null;
    try
    {
        Query query = null;

        query        = session.createQuery(UMRSQLInt.DOMAIN_NAME_LIST);
        objectNamesList = query.list();            

    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while getDocumentationDomainNamesList:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return objectNamesList;
}

/**
 * @return List<UMRDTO>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UMRDTO> getDocumentationDomainComboNamesList(Session session)
{
    List<UMRDTO> objectNamesList  = null;
    try
    {
        Query query = null;

        query        = session.createQuery(UMRSQLInt.DOMAINCOMBO_NAME_LIST);
        objectNamesList = query.list();       
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while getDocumentationDomainComboNamesList:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return objectNamesList;
}


/**
 * @return List<UMRLanguageDTO>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UMRDTO> getDocumentationList(Session session)
{
    List<UMRDTO> documentationList = null;

    try
    {
        Query query = null;
        query        = session.createQuery(UMRSQLInt.DOCUMENTATION_LIST);
        documentationList = query.list();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while getDocumentationList:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return documentationList;
}

/**
 * @param documentationDTO
 * 
 */
public void insertDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO, Session session)
{  
    try
    {            
        session.save(documentationDTO);
        logger.debug("inserted new documentation object.");
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while documentation:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


/**
 * Updates the documentation
 *
 * @param documentationDTO
 * @param userProfileDTO
 *
 */
public void updateDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO,
                                            Session session)
{
   try
    {   
        session.update(documentationDTO);
        logger.debug("updated selected documentation.");
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while updateDocumentation:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * deletes the Documentation
 *
 * @param documentationDTO     
 *
 */
public void deleteDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO,
                            Session session)
{
   try
    {
        session.delete(documentationDTO);
        logger.debug("deleted selected documentation.");
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception while deleteDocumentation:" + "Cause:"
                     + e.getCause() + "Reason:" + e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the `,` in this line? `MMTUtil.setDomainDocumentationMap(,documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());`

Comment: yes before "," should be a key which this should return
public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

Comment: This seems like a typo to me?!

Comment: what is this dao?

Comment: Are you trying to call a method (which is defined with a single argument), by passing two arguments.

Comment: No its has 2 arguments

Comment: according to the code in the class you give `setDomainComboDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainComboDocumentationMap)` method has 1 argument ! ( the other one to, 1 argument )

Comment: What should `setDomainDocumentationMap` do? 1) Should it replace `MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap` or 2) should it add a value to it? There is no need to add a key for the first use case

Comment: It should add value to it

Comment: @ppasler TreeMap.Entry<> is it required to be used? I don't think I have used it to add entry to the map 
heck of a confussion

Comment: where shall I add my data into the map? i got 2 of them

Comment: Then the method should look something like this:     public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(String key, String value) {
        MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.put(key, value);
    }

Comment: What will this do ?